# Ace Admin datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker

I'm pretty new here and being an front-end engineer as well.
Recently trying to use Ace Admin.
When I use datetimepicker, I wouldn't like user to change the hour & minute through pressing up & down arrow.

[up & down arrow like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0lcD.png)

I would like them to change time through clicking hour or minute and then choose those option whick setup already.

[try to let them click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fxtu.png)

Is there any possible to make those arrows disable and disappear ?
I try bellow to make those arrows disappear and it works. But click function still there.

```
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
      time: 'glyphicon timeWithText',
      up:'none',
      down:'none',
    },
  });
```

Please help in this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find this website have all properites can be changed in datetimepicker.
https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/#tooltips

Updated here just in case any other people has same issue.
Please noted that some properties are not supported by older version so make sure your CDN is latest.